# Performance problems using a Spring Batch FieldSetMapper to map into an object that will be written with a JpaItemWriter?

Tags: jpa, spring-batch, deltaspike

We are writing a set of Spring Batch jobs that read values from text files and use that information to update objects that are read and written from the database using JPA. These jobs are **not** run in a web container, but on an application server. My problem seems to be with how the `EntityManager` is configured.

The code reads files from various vendors that update an order's status. The text file specifies the customer by name and the order by date/time. If the customer doesn't exist, the line from the text file is skipped. If the order exists, we update it. If not, then we create it.

We currently use DeltaSpike to get instances of our DAO objects like this:

```
DependentProvider<CustomerDaoImpl> provider = BeanProvider.getDependent(CustomerDaoImpl.class);
ICustomerDao custDao = provider.get();
```

I cache the DAO objects in my mapper so I am only getting them once. But every call to `BeanProvider.getDependent()` creates a new `EntityManager` through "Spring Batch Magic." The `EntityManager` is specified thusly:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseBatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Produces
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", System.getProperty("JDBC_URL"));
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", System.getProperty("APP_SCHEMA"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", System.getProperty("APP_DB_ID"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", System.getProperty("APP_DB_PWD"));
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(System.getProperty("PU_NAME"), properties);
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

I tried caching the `EntityManager`, but a new instance of the `BaseBatchConfiguration` class is used every time. This means that each DAO gets created with it's own `EntityManager`, so no real object caching is taking place across DAOs (reading a customer with the `CustomerDaoImpl` isn't cached and used when `OrderDaoImpl` loads an order that references that same customer).

This is causing a lot of unwanted object loading as we process through the text file.

Is there some other way we should be declaring our `EntityManager`?

Comment: I would use a JBatch implementation which supports CDI directly. There is no need to use Spring-Batch.

Comment: What is DeltaSpike adding to this?  Why use it at all?

Comment: Our model and DAO layer objects are in another project that uses CDI, so when the project was proto-typed there were issues getting Spring Batch to recognize them. Adding Deltaspike to the project fixed that issue. (NOTE: That all happened before I was on the project so I don't know the details.)